# awk: Print line numbers seperated by comma

Tags: awk, gawk

```
awk '{for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {gsub(/[^[:alnum:]]/, " "); print tolower($i)": "NR | "sort -V | uniq";}}' input.txt
```

With above code, I get output as:

```
line1: 2
line1: 3
line1: 5
line2: 1
line2: 2
line3: 10
```

I want it like below:

```
line1: 2, 3, 5
line2: 1, 2
lin23: 10
```

How to achieve it?

Comment: er, that doesn't appear to run, unless I'm missing something... can you check that the braces are in the right place?

Comment: Edited the command. It lists unique words in an input file along with the line numbers the words appear. I want to list each word followed by the line numbers separated by commas.

Comment: what's in input.txt?

Comment: @glenn jackman, anything. The script is supposed to list all the words each on a line along with the line numbers separated by commas.

Comment: Look, we're offering you our time for free. If you're not willing to provide the minimum effort to show your input, you're wasting all our time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use gawk's [array features](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Array-Example.html). I'll provide actual code once I hack it up.

```
awk '{for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
    gsub(/[^[:alnum:]]/, " "); 
    arr[tolower($i)] = arr[tolower($i)]NR", "}
  } 
  END {
    for (x in arr) {
      print x": "substr(arr[x], 1, length(arr[x])-2);
  }}' input.txt | sort
```

Note that this includes duplicate line numbers if a word appears multiple times on the same lines.

Comment: If I remove NR from the print command, I get unique words properly sorted. How do I add a comma separated list of line numbers these words appear? For example, if "Word1" is appearing on lines 2, 4, 6, I would like the output as: `word1: 2, 4, 6`. I am not able to figure out how I can do this using arrays, as suggested by you.

Comment: I don't know of a way to do it without using an array, although there probably is one.

Comment: Awesome!!! I am now trying to find out a way to avoid duplicate line numbers. Many thanks!

Comment: I am still trying to rectify duplicate numbers. If you can help, that would be great.

Comment: Hm, I'll see what I can come up with.

Answer (score 0):

using perl...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

while(<>){
  if( /(\w+):\s*(\d+)/){       # extract the parts
     $arr{lc($1)}{$2} ++       # count them
  };    
}

for my $k (sort keys %arr){    # print sorted alpha
  print "$k: ";
  $lines=$arr{$k};
  print join(", ",(sort {$a<=>$b} keys %$lines)),"\n";  print sorted numerically
}
```

This solution removes ans sorts the duplicated numbers. Is this what you needed?